# How to plot the CPU usage of Matlab

Tags: matlab

i have a code that displays the CPU usage of Matlab, my problem is how to PLOT the CPU usage over time because the this code does NOT save any variables in the workspace,I need a method for storing the CPU usage in an array when the code is run so that i can plot it
Thanks for your time. 
here is the code:

```
function hcol = CPU_monitor
h = create_gui;
end

function mon = createMonitor
MatlabProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(); %// "Matlab" process
cpuIdleProcess = 'Idle';
mon.NumOfCPU = double(System.Environment.ProcessorCount);
mon.ProcPerfCounter.Matlab  = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter('Process', '% Processor Time', MatlabProcess.ProcessName);
mon.ProcPerfCounter.cpuIdle = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter('Process', '% Processor Time', cpuIdleProcess);
end

function updateMeasure(obj,evt,hfig)
h = guidata(hfig);

%// Calculate the cpu usage
cpu.total = 100 - h.mon.ProcPerfCounter.cpuIdle.NextValue / h.mon.NumOfCPU;
cpu.matlab = h.mon.ProcPerfCounter.Matlab.NextValue / h.mon.NumOfCPU;

%// update the display
set(h.txtTotalCPU,'String',num2str(cpu.total,'%5.2f %%'))
set(h.txtMatlabCPU,'String',num2str(cpu.matlab,'%5.2f %%'))
end

function StartMonitor(obj,evt)
h = guidata(obj);
start(h.t)
end

function StopMonitor(obj,evt)
h = guidata(obj);
stop(h.t)
end

function h = create_gui %// The boring part
h.fig = figure('Unit','Pixels','Position',[200 800 240 120],'MenuBar','none','Name','CPU usage %','NumberTitle','off');
h.btnStart = uicontrol('Callback',@StartMonitor,'Position',[10 80 100 30],'String', 'START');
h.btnStart = uicontrol('Callback',@StopMonitor,'Position',[130 80 100 30 ],'String', 'STOP');
h.lbl1 = uicontrol('HorizontalAlignment','right','Position',[10 50 100 20],'String','TOTAL :','Style','text');
h.txtTotalCPU = uicontrol('Position',[130 50 100 20],'String','0','Style','text');
h.lbl2 = uicontrol('HorizontalAlignment','right','Position',[10 10 100 20],'String','Matlab :','Style','text');
h.txtMatlabCPU = uicontrol('Position',[130 10 100 20],'String','0','Style','text');
movegui(h.fig,'center')

%// create the monitor
h.mon = createMonitor;

%// Create the timer
h.t = timer;
h.t.Period = 0.25;
h.t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
h.t.TimerFcn = {@updateMeasure,h.fig};
h.t.TasksToExecute = Inf;

%// store the handle collection
guidata(h.fig,h)
end
```

Comment: Plotting it as it's running or when it's finished?

Comment: I need to plot it when it's finished

Comment: define "finished", when you press stop? when you exit the program?

Comment: when i press stop

Comment: i need to plot the Overall usage of cpu over time (i.e. the variations that occur on the cpu through an interval of time)

Comment: so you also need some clock or time when this have happened

Comment: yes exactly, i think "clock" command may help

Answer (score 1):

one way is to save the variables to a file and read and plot it after you stop. So you add a `dlmwrite` command in the updateMeasure function, a `tic` to start the timer in StartMonitor, and `dlmread` and `plot` in StopMonitor. Of course this is quick and dirty as the file created will be needed to be deleted or checked so you wont continue to append to it in the later uses.

This is everything

```
function hcol = CPU_monitor
h = create_gui;
end


function mon = createMonitor
MatlabProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess(); %// "Matlab" process
cpuIdleProcess = 'Idle';
mon.NumOfCPU = double(System.Environment.ProcessorCount);
mon.ProcPerfCounter.Matlab  = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter('Process', '% Processor Time', MatlabProcess.ProcessName);
mon.ProcPerfCounter.cpuIdle = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter('Process', '% Processor Time', cpuIdleProcess);
end

function updateMeasure(obj,evt,hfig)

h = guidata(hfig);

%// Calculate the cpu usage
cpu.total = 100 - h.mon.ProcPerfCounter.cpuIdle.NextValue / h.mon.NumOfCPU;
cpu.matlab = h.mon.ProcPerfCounter.Matlab.NextValue / h.mon.NumOfCPU;
dlmwrite('cpulog.txt', [toc, cpu.total , cpu.matlab], '-append');

   %// update the display
set(h.txtTotalCPU,'String',num2str(cpu.total,'%5.2f %%'))
set(h.txtMatlabCPU,'String',num2str(cpu.matlab,'%5.2f %%'))
end

function StartMonitor(obj,evt)
h = guidata(obj);
start(h.t)
tic
end

function StopMonitor(obj,evt)
h = guidata(obj);
stop(h.t)
data=dlmread('cpulog.txt');
data(1,:)=[]; 
figure;plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,1) ,data(:,3));
legend('total cpu','matlab cpu'); xlabel('sec'); ylabel('%');
end

function h = create_gui %// The boring part
h.fig = figure('Unit','Pixels','Position',[200 800 240 120],'MenuBar','none','Name','CPU usage %','NumberTitle','off');
h.btnStart = uicontrol('Callback',@StartMonitor,'Position',[10 80 100 30],'String', 'START');
h.btnStart = uicontrol('Callback',@StopMonitor,'Position',[130 80 100 30 ],'String', 'STOP');
h.lbl1 = uicontrol('HorizontalAlignment','right','Position',[10 50 100 20],'String','TOTAL :','Style','text');
h.txtTotalCPU = uicontrol('Position',[130 50 100 20],'String','0','Style','text');
h.lbl2 = uicontrol('HorizontalAlignment','right','Position',[10 10 100 20],'String','Matlab :','Style','text');
h.txtMatlabCPU = uicontrol('Position',[130 10 100 20],'String','0','Style','text');
movegui(h.fig,'center')

%// create the monitor
h.mon = createMonitor;

%// Create the timer
h.t = timer;
h.t.Period = 0.25;
h.t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
h.t.TimerFcn = {@updateMeasure,h.fig};
h.t.TasksToExecute = Inf;

%// store the handle collection
guidata(h.fig,h)
end
```